# Where are my photos in this 60GB iPhoto Library folder?

Tags: finder, photos.app, folders

HELP!!

59.4GB "iPhoto Library" folder only contains a few folders (see attached screen shots), none of which seem to contain any original photos or even any image files?

The "Versions" folder was my best bet but it doesn't actually contain any images. None of these folders do.

Can't seem to find any information through Google on whether my photos are somewhere within this supposed Database folder and the folders within it. Not sure why it is 60GB if it doesn't contain any hefty files, just a bunch of system files or whatever.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the 'Database' folder contain the 60GB?

Answer (score 1):

if you go to ~/Users/'yourusername'/Pictures there should be a file(s) with Photo.Library in name. If you right click on this file and select 'Show Package Contents' you can find your photos. There may be several folders. Many of mine were in 'Master' folder.